# How to force eclipse to republish project when changing source in another module

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-wtp

I have multi module maven project.
One of the modules is actual web application, the JBoss is the server.
Other subprojects are dependencies for the web project.

I am running it in JBoss embedded in eclipse. Pretty straightforward configuration.

When executed from within eclipse, if I do mvn clean, mvn package - then clean + publish to JBoss, everything works wonderfully.

If I change source code for the web project, eclipse detects the need to republish automatically and does job well.

However if I change source in the non-web subproject, eclipse does not detect change and I have to mvn clean, mvn package, then publish to JBoss manually for it to pick the code change.
This is annoying since packaging job takes about a minute, then publishing job takes another 30 seconds. I have to clean since simply packaging without clean does not pick the change either.

Is there a way to configure things in the eclipse so that any source change in any subproject/module is automatically recognized by eclipse and it would republish to JBoss upon selecting "run"?

There is another bad side effect - debugging of the source that is not web project is impossible - eclipse's debugger does not see that source. It sees only source of the web module.

Thanks,
Nikolay

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your web project has dependencies on the other modules(projects) defined in the pom and in the eclipse project. you can check that in the build settings. If they are not there then it probably means that the project file was not generated from your maven .pom file.  You can generate that by running 
mvn eclipse:eclipse

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help - eclipse still does not recognize the change in subprojects

Comment: You should be doing an exploded deployment. for the more complex setups JRebel may help. http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/